# Engineering/mathmatics question

Tags: functions, optimization

I have an equation $M(x)= -15.328x^2+176.44x-352.88$ (a parabola) and also $V(x) = -30.657x + 176.44$. I want to know how to find $x$ where the values of $M$ and $V$ combined are the lowest, I'm expecting there to be $2$ values. I know $M(x) = 0$ at $2.58$ and $8.93$ and $V(x) = 0$ at $5.755$?

To put it in context, I'm trying to find where to cut a beam In two places where the combined bending moments $(M)$ and shear force $(V)$ are least. I'm not sure on the method to use. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Add the two together and minimize $M+V$.

Comment: If $M$ is a moment and $V$ is a shear force, you should not add both: they don't have the same unit. You should probably express the stresses as the sum of the stresses due to bending and to shear, assuming linearity ($\sigma=-My/I$ for the bending, and Jouravski formula maybe for the shear?).

Comment: @EdFurniss I edited my answer. Let me know if its incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

$M(x)+V(x)=-15.328x^2+(176.44-30.657)x+(-352.88+176.44)$

$-15.328x^2+145.783x-176.44$

The parabola is upside down, you want the minimum value where $y=0$.

In this case, you could use the quadratic formula in the form $ax^2+bx+c$

$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

In the equation $y=-15.328x^2+145.783x-176.44$, we have $a=-15.328$, $b=145.783$ and $c=-176.44$

So if you substitue the values you will have $x=1.489$ and $x=8.088$

Comment: Unfortunately, since the quadratic coefficient is a negative number $-15.328$, the point $x=-4.755$ that you've found is not the place where $M(x)+V(x)$ is minimized but is instead the place where it is maximized.

Comment: @LeeMosher I edited the answer.